# Difference between margin and padding in this example

Tags: html, css

I know the difference between margin and padding but I have an issue with this code and don't understand what differentiate margin and padding.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  width: 340px;
  text-align: center;
}

.facts {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- your favorite animal's name goes here -->
  <h3 id="name">Sharpei</h3>
  <!-- your favorite animal's image goes here -->
  <img src="http://i61.servimg.com/u/f61/12/41/85/52/sharpe10.jpg" alt="Sharpei">
  <div class="facts">
    <!-- your favorite animal's interesting fact goes here -->
    <p class="presentation">Le Shar-Pei a ensuite été entrainé au combat, mais d'autres races plus puissantes et plus agressives se sont peu à peu substituées à lui.</p>
    <ul>
      <!-- your favorite animal's list items go here -->
      <li><span>Scientific name</span>: Shar-peï</li>
      <li><span>Average Length</span>: 45cm</li>
      <li><span>Average Lifespan</span>: 11 years</li>
      <li><span>Habitat</span>: My house </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- your favorite animal's description goes here -->
    <p>Le Shar-peï, Shar-pei ou sharpeï est un chien d'origine chinoise qui se caractérise par sa peau ample qui retombe en plis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text sticks to border and I wanted to add a padding to add space between the border and the text but when I do that using `padding: 5px;` it changes the width of the box.

Can someone help/explain ?

Thanks

Comment: read about box model .. and look at `box-sizing:border-box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default the rendered width of an element is equal to the width plus any border or padding. However, you can change this behaviour with the `box-sizing` property. Try adding:

```
padding: 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

See: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthiastotschnig/g7b5aher/) ; [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

An element's **padding** controls the amount of **space between the element and its border**.

An element's **margin** controls the amount of **space between an element's border and surrounding elements**.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to define the  element as a box and then provide it the desired padding.

Try adding:

```
`.facts{display: inline-block; width : 300px; padding: 50 px; margin: 100px;}`
```

Here, you'll see padding added inside the box and a margin of 100px from neighboring elements or boxes. Further, to test it you may want to add a background color.